On Downloading the Excelsheet the link is being displayed as HYPERLINK formula and only turns into a link upon clicking the cell and moving out
I am using APEX 22.2.0 and I have added a download button to download required data into multiple sheets in an excel, for which I am using as_xlsx package by Anton Scheffer.
I am using a SQL query to retrieve the data and I want one column to be a link in the excelsheet, but on download the cell value is being displayed as the HYPERLINK formula and turns into a link only upon clicking on the cell and moving out. Is there any way through which when I download the Excelsheet  the column with links gets downloaded as links and not a hyperlink formula.
This is the SQL query that I am using:
as_xlsx.query2sheet( 'SELECT ''=HYPERLINK("''||COURSE_LINK||''","''||COURSE_NAME||''")''  FROM COURSE;', p_sheet => 1 );

I confirmed the query returns correct information to Excel but the field appears with the entire text as written above and not as a true hyperlink.
Is there a way to get this to populate hyperlinks properly in Excel without the additional steps?
On excelsheet download it is being displayed like this:Excelsheet cell displaying hyperlink formula
And i want it to be displayed like: Excelsheet cell displaying link
